# jsp:useBean call a specific method in a class

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

How can I call a specific method in a class using this tag?

`<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="??" class="com.example.User" type="com.example.User" />`

Comment: Using that tag? You don't. You put the bean in scope in the Java code and use JSP EL.

Comment: Java: `request.setAttribute("foo", new User())`, JSP: `${foo.someMethod()}` give or take. See any of a zillion answers for "calling bean method in JSP" for multiple ways of doing this. No clue what having multiple methods/JSPs in a single controller has to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your bean User has a method called getName()

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="request" class="com.example.User" />
// ...
<h1>Hello <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="name" /></h1>
```

The scope could be something else than **request** : depends on what you want (session, page, etc)

---

EDIT: your second question was about calling a business method in your jsp

The fact is, you **should not** call business method into your JSPs. Your JSP pages should only display static (html, etc) and dynamic (beans for example) content. If you follow MVC pattern, business job is delegated to servlets. Your JSPs are only simple views (reading properties of beans) and are forbidden (in directory WEB-INF).

### For your JSP pages, proceed as following:

1. Action of html form is your servlet controller (method POST)
2. Add hidden input to help servlet recognize what to do: `<input
   type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />` or `<input
   type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />`

You can also display dynamic content (beans). For that, you should consider using JSTL.

Example (servlet sends an ArrayList of Movie beans on request scope):

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.results}" var="movie">
   // ${movie.title}
   // etc
</c:forEach>
```

### For your servlet controller, proceed as following:

In **doPost** method (because we're using POST method in html form), you can dispatch business logic depending on action received: `request.getParameter("action")`

If action is **update**, then we perform update business logic.

If action is **register**, then we perform register business logic.

etc ...

Now, we can store some data in request scope to communicate to jsp page:

```
ArrayList<Movie> results = new ArrayList<Movie>();
results.add(new Movie(...));
// etc...
request.setAttribute("results", results);
```

And finally, send data and display jsp:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/update.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

---

An example of web.xml (with a servlet mapped as welcome file index.jsp)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.Search</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Update</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.Update</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Update</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Update.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: @ThreaT : Your edit was rejected because you completely replaced the original content of the answer. I'd recommend adding your own answer containing your final implementation if you think it would be useful for other users.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield: No, because I'm using the exact same answer as this one, I'm just displaying it in a different order. If one reads the code before deciding they'll notice that.

Comment: I saw your edit. It seems to be a good implementation of my answer, except in your servlet: maybe you should consider having business methods in beans instead of in the servlet itself. Anyway, it seems you can't edit my answer. But actually, you don't have to. I gave you a global idea of how to do it. Maybe you should mark it as resolved if my answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="request" class="com.example.User" type="com.example.User" />
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*" />
<c:set var="saveStatus" value="${user.save()}" />
```