# Passing String parameters to java function using jsp

Tags: java, function, jsp, onclick

Well, i have a java function which accepts two Strings and one long datatype to carry out an operation.

I want to call this java function based on the return value of an if statement using my jsp page. This function should be called on the click of the button and I want the button to change its text once the function is called. How do I do achieve this?

So far, I have done this :

```
<%String arg1="abc",arg2="Def";
long arg3=1000;%>
```

And based on the if statement return value, have called the java function

```
<%if(true)
out.println("<tr><td>"+arg1+" has requested confirmation</td>");
out.println("<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Confirm\" onClick= \"MyClass.MyFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3);\"</td></tr>");
```

Using the above code, MyFunction is not being called (it's imported properly into my jsp page, that i have checked) and after the click i want the text of the button to change to "Confirmed".

Comment: You are extremely confused. `Onclick` is a client side Javascript function which knows nothing at all about your server side Java code.

Comment: Gosh..!! I'm feeling like a retard.. Can you suggest me how to invoke the java function inside my jsp?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke a business method? Generally it is not recommended to do so - refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258945/7873361